# Random UFO, flies off screen, never to return

Tags: c#, xna

I implemented code that would check whether the ufo's X position is greater than the width of the game screen.  Then if it is, the ufo is dead.

I have also implemented code that generates a new number if the ufo is dead, in which case, when the right number is generated, then the saucer should fly across the screen.

I don't know why it isn't doing that.  The saucer only flys across once, randomly.

The code for the saucer is below:

```
if (ufo.alive == true)
            {
                // also, we need to make it move
                ufo.Xpos = ufo.Xpos + 1;

                if (MissileFired != null)
                {
                    // if you miss, and the ufo carries on, it will go forever.
                    //so 
                    if (ufo.Xpos > 1000)
                    {
                     // kill the ufo if it goes off the screen.....   
                        ufo.alive = false;
                    }
```

the code to generate the random number is:

```
if (ufo.alive == false)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);

                {
                    if (randomNumber == 1)
                        ufo.alive = true;
                }
```

As you can see, I don't know why it doesn't generate the ufo again after it has flown across and off the screen.

Comment: The above code does not seem to be sufficient to say why not. Did you ever set the `Xpos` back to the other side of the screen?

Comment: I think @Tejs is right. After setting ufo.alive = true; you should do ufo.Xpos = 0; or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Dont create a new random every cycle.

take out of your Update method and declare it as:

```
 class Game1: Game {
    public static readonly Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecs);
    ....
 }

 ....

 if (ufo.alive == false) {
    int randomNumber = Game1.random.Next(0, 100);
    if (randomNumber == 1)
    {
      ufo.alive = true;
      ufo.Xpos = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still does not generate a ufo once more. I appreciate your help though

Comment: you should set ufo.XPos = 0, and I wonder if MissileFired is sometimes not null... you should debug it... is easy... select the line you want to inspect and press F9 to set a breakpoint... with F11 you can execute step by step, and you can watch the values are taking your variables and if a code is executed or not...

Comment: @hatchet You are right... I was in a mistake because remember that if I did not pass a random seed it always behaves in  the same way... maybe the random default seed depends on time elapsed from the application start... or maybe I'm was bit crazy... :)